# Storing a list of methods in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I have a list of method that I would like to call in a specific order. Therefore I would want to store them either in an ordered list or in a table with a specified index. This way the list would be the only thing to change the day we want to change the call order.

I found [this article](http://ebersys.blogspot.com/2006/08/arrays-of-methods-in-c.html) explaining how to do it using an array and delegates. But I read in the comments and some other places that it could also be done using a Dictionary and or LinQ. Any advices ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can define `Action` objects, which are parameterless delegates that return `void`. Each action is a pointer to a method.

```
// Declare the list
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

// Add two delegates to the list that point to 'SomeMethod' and 'SomeMethod2'
actions.Add( ()=> SomeClass.SomeMethod(param1) );
actions.Add( ()=> OtherClass.SomeMethod2() );

// Later on, you can walk through these pointers
foreach(var action in actions)
    // And execute the method
    action.Invoke();
```

Comment: You can omit Invoke() btw, just call action()

Comment: Everything is ok but Queue is much more suitable for the OP's task rather than List, imo. Isn't it?

Comment: Don't think so. It's just a static list, no need for queue'ing or dequeue'ing tasks, as they won't change dynamically. He might want to re-run the batch a couple of times etc.

Answer (score 9):

How about a `Queue<Action>` ?

```
var queue = new Queue<Action>();

queue.Enqueue(() => foo());
queue.Enqueue(() => bar());

while(queue.Count != 0)
{
    Action action = queue.Dequeue();
    action();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you consider using a [`Queue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) it's FIFO , store delegates in `Queue` and when you call `Dequeue` it will call your methods in a specified manner.

What about using Multicast Delegate , it stores delegates in a LinkList, so when you call Invoke() , it will be called in a specified manner.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to look at [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). Hope it 's what you lookng for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `List<>` which would fit your need pretty well:

```
delegate void MyFunction(...);
List<MyFunction> delegateList;
```

If your delegate returns void, you can use `event`. Multiple delegates can be added to a single event invocation list and will be called in the order they were added.

```
delegate void MyEvent(...);
event MyEventEventHandler MyEvent;
```

`Dictionary` [order is undefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) and it's meant to make a lookup.