# Storing different actions in Queue (need clarification)

Tags: c#, lambda, queue

**TLDR; Why does this work.**

```
    Queue<Action> queue = new Queue<Action>();
    queue.Enqueue(() => Load("Scene01"));
```

**But not this.**

```
    Queue<Action> queue = new Queue<Action>();
    queue.Enqueue(Load("Scene01"));
```

I was trying to create a simple load system that allow scheduling multiple loads at the same time. Found it would be simple storing request as action which then gets added to a queue that some function makes its way through.

The loading function I use is overloaded, and thus the actions created will differ from one another. At first I though I'd be require to create some kind of generic system that could take different actions, but then I found this.

[Storing a list of methods in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767942/storing-a-list-of-methods-in-c-sharp)

**Question**
Why is it that you can pass a function that doesn't match the action using a lambda expression?

```
Queue<Action> queue = new Queue<Action>();

private void Load() { }

private void Load(string n) { }

private void QueueLoad()
{
    // This match action signature.
    queue.Enqueue(Load);

    // This does not match, nor work.
    queue.Enqueue(Load("Scene01"));

    // Adding lambda expression and it works. Why?
    queue.Enqueue(() => Load("Scene01"));
}
```

Comment: Your second code block doesn't work because you are calling the `Load` method and returning it's result to store in the queue.

Comment: Ah, now I see. I notice that changing "Load" to "Load()" gives the same result. So I guess the lambda make sure its the actual function being passed. Thanks a lot man, it had me puzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
queue.Enqueue(Load);
```

This works because `Load` is a [method group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c) and can be converted to `Action`.

```
queue.Enqueue(() => Load("Scene01"));
```

This works because the lambda expression takes no arguments and returns nothing, hence implicitly convertible to `Action`.

```
queue.Enqueue(Load("Scene01"));
```

This does not work because `Load("Scene01")` is a method call, and the method doesn't return anything, you are trying to pass `void` into `Enqueue` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.