# Create a list with methods with a return value C#

Tags: c#, list, methods

I a making a little program that wants to analyse the gender of German nouns in a corpus. For that I have created some methods with a string as return value. For instance, I want to check if there is a definite in front of the noun in the corpus and see if it contains "der", "die" or "das". Deepening on which it returns different values. Like below:

```cs
private string definitearticle()
{ 
    // code, where gender is the string which we return - if we can't determine
    // the gender it returns "Cannot determine"
    return gender;
}

private string indefinitearticle()
{ 
    // code, where gender is the string which we return - if we can't determine
    // the gender it returns "Cannot determine"
    return gender;
}
```

I want to loop each one of the methods one by one until I no longer get "Cannot determine" as the return value like below with a list of pointers to the methods (like in [Storing a list of methods in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767942/storing-a-list-of-methods-in-c-sharp/3767964)):

```cs
var methods = new List<(System.Action check, string caption)>()
{
    (definitearticle, "Definite article"),
    (indefinitearticle, "Indefinite article"),
};

foreach (var method in methods)
{
    gender = method.check.Invoke();
    if (gender != "Cannot determine")
    {
        // store the outcome that was returned to a list
        break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to use a `List` with `methods` that have a `return value` (in this case a `string`). Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: I noticed that you have a list of names and you want to search for one or more letters in it? is it right?

Comment: use Func<T, TResult> instead of Action<T>. Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-6.0

Comment: I think I'd define an enum to represent the genders/cannot and then have a `new List<Func<string, GenderEnum>>()` - I couldn't work out what the `caption` member of the tuple was for, but feel free to restore it if it's used elsewhere. The func `Func<string, Gender>` takes a string param, which I presume is what you're going to pass in to examine..

Comment: (But if you were e.g. looping over the corpus which was a list of words represented as a string[], and passing an int index to examine, so that you can look at the N-1'th word to see if it's der/die etc then you'd need to be making methods that accepted a `string[], int` and returned `GenderEnum` so it'd be a `Func<string[], int, GenderEnum>` - anyways, that's the pattern: `Func<T1,T2,..TN, TReturn>`, minimally just the TReturn

Comment: Thanks! I am analysing wikipedia data line by line so it is for that names. Caption is just the caption of the function that found the right gender for statistical proposes when I write about the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to store a method as a type that has a return value, you should use `Func<TResult>` instead of `Action`. It works the same way as an action, except that you additionaly can input the return type as the last generic type. So if you for example had a method where it had two parameters with the types of `int` and `bool` and a return type of `string`, you would say

```
var myReturnMethod = new Func<int, bool, string>((intVal, boolVal) => intVal.ToString() + boolVal.ToString());
```

In your case, just replace your methods variable initialization with this code:

```
var methods = new List<(Func<string> check, string caption)>
    {
        (definitearticle, "Definite article"),
        (indefinitearticle, "Indefinite article"),
    };
```

### Edit:

On request of the OP, here's how you'd initialize the methods variable if you only wanted it to contain a collection of the methods, without the caption:

```
        var methods = new List<Func<string>>
        {
            definitearticle,
            indefinitearticle,
        };
```

More info on Functions can be found at [the official microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick!

Comment: No problem! Happy coding and cheers!

Comment: Just one more thing, say that I want to remove the caption in the list `methods`, how would I write it then?

Comment: I edited my answer to demonstrate how you'd do that.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot :-)