# Create a list with methods with a return value C# and optional argument C#

Tags: c#, func, optional-arguments

I have a list with methods that I am calling from a loop like below (with the help of a previous question: [Create a list with methods with a return value C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70732477/create-a-list-with-methods-with-a-return-value-c-sharp/70732640?noredirect=1#comment125044382_70732640)):

```
string method;

var methods = new List<(Func<string> analysismethod, string caption)>
{
    (definitearticle, "Definite article"),
    (indefinitearticle, "Indefinite article"),
};
for (int i = 0; i < methods.Count(); i++)
{
    string gender = methods[i].analysismethod.Invoke();
    if (gender != "Cannot determine")
    {
        method = methods[i].caption;
        break;
    }
}
```

What I want to do now is to add an optional argument (a `string`) to each of the methods in `methods` (so I can reuse them for other purposes as well) like in:

```
definitearticle (word = default)
{
}
```

However, when I try add the optional argument, I get these errors:

```
Error   CS1950  The best overloaded Add method 'List<(Func<string> analysismethod, string caption)>.Add((Func<string> analysismethod, string caption))' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from '(method group, string)' to '(Func<string> analysismethod, string caption)'
```

How can I solve this?

edit: The reason why I want to use them with a specified string sometimes is that I sometimes want to analyse them for a specific input, whereas I sometimes just want to check for a default position in a sentence that I store in a `struct`:

```
public string indefinitearticle(string word = default)
{       
    if (word == default) 
    {
        word = AnalysisData.wordBeforeNoun;
    }

    string gender = default;
    if (word == "eine")
    {
        gender = "Fem";
    }
    else if (word == "ein")
    {
        gender = "Non fem";
    }
    
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(gender) ? "Cannot determine" : gender;
}
```

Comment: Delegates should be for a single purpose. If the code you posted doesn't need the string, don't add it to those methods, use a new list of delegates with a different signature for the other purpose.

Comment: Regarding the error message... parameter defaults are not part of the method signature. If the method has the parameter, any delegate pointing to it must have a matching signature as if you removed the default from the method.

Comment: Use overloads instead of optional parameter (that actually what compile will do - generate corresponding overload methods) - than you can use both overloads for different purposes. `definitearticle() => definitearticle("default")`

Comment: That is, the problem would be solved if I have the same optional arguments to all of the methods? That would be a nice solutions since I intend to do just that once I am finished with the first one.

Comment: @Fabio That would be a solution, but I do not want to do that either since I want to be able to reuse the same analysis methods just sometimes with some user defined words.

Comment: No, it would not be solved by that because delegates signatures don't consider parameter defaults.

Comment: I updated the post a bit to show what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce overload methods

```
public string DefiniteArticle(string param1, string param2)  
{
    // calculate and return "some string";
}

public string DefiniteArticle()
{
    return DefiniteArticle("default value1", "default value2");
}
```

Now with parameterless overload you are able to add it to the collection of `Func<string>` to satisfy it's type and use "original" method for other purposes.

```
var delagates = new Func<string>[] { DefiniteArticle }
```

Notice that delegate are types as any other `int` or `string` - for being able to add method to the collection of delegates method should be same type.  Overload method allows us to "decorate" original method with the required delegate type

Comment: Overloads will help to create an overload method which will satisfy delegate type.

Comment: Yes, but I want the calculations to be exactly the same - I just want to be able to change the input if I am not going for the default case.

Comment: @KGB91, overload methods doing exactly what you are trying to achieve _change the input if I am not going for the default case_

Comment: Yes, but then I will have to do have the calculations duplicated since the only thing I want to do is to have another input, the calculations will be exactly the same.

Comment: What you mean by "duplicated calculation", calculation will exists in one method and will be called by overload.

Comment: Ah, I see... I call the function with the calculations if I do not want specify an argument. That is indeed a creative workaround.